# How to assess correlation when each variable is measured by independent replicates?

Tags: regression

I frequently measure multiple variables, in multiple replicates, at many sites. For instance, I might measure bacterial abundance and bacterial growth rates, each in 3 replicates, at many sites. Each replicate is independently sampled *and* each variable is measured in a different sample (i.e., I can't measure both bacterial abundance and growth rate in the same sample).

I'd like to test for correlation between those variables. The problem is, since the variables are measured independently, the variables are not paired. Replicate 1 of variable A is not related to replicate 1 of variable B, any more than it is to replicate 2 of variable B.

I could test for correlation among the average of replicates at each site - but that seems blunt, since you lose information about variation among replicates for each parameter. I can imagine some kind of resampling approach, where I randomly select one replicate for each variable at each site. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify the distinctions you are making among "sample," "site," and "replicate"?  From the text it appears you are sometimes measuring abundance and sometimes growth rate.  That does not seem to have anything to do, *per se,* either with sampling or replication.  What is a "site"?  Precisely how does "sampling" occur and, within this framework, how is "replication" conducted?

Comment: In my case, a "site" refers to a geographic location; sites will be separated by kilometers at a minimum. To sample means to collect a few liters of seawater, perhaps in a bucket. To measure each replicate of each parameter, I then collect a few milliliters from the bucket and do the measurement. Does that clarify?

Comment: Yes! That is very helpful.  It suggests reasonable models of correlation among measurements.

Comment: @whuber: I'm a bit confused as to your last comment - what are the reasonable models of correlation among measurements, that you are referring to?

Comment: To clarify the question a little more: At each site you take one bucket or three buckets? From each bucket you take one or many samples (i.e., milliliters)? From each sample you make exactly one measurement (either abundance or growth rate)? But why then do you have three measurements per bucket (one time abundance, one time growth, and the last measurement?)? From how I understand your design so far, probably bucket should be the relevant random variable.

Comment: Henrik, sorry I've been unclear. From each bucket, I measure bacterial abundance 3 times ( each measurement is actually made from an individual, 1 ml subsample) and growth rate 3 times.
The core of my question is: I think I would know what to do if each individual abundance measurement were naturally paired with an individual growth rate measurement. But since they are not paired, what is the best way to plug them into a regression model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I think the only viable way to go is what you don't want to do: Use the bucket as the level of analyses. That is, aggregate the 3 measurements within each bucket and you have your pairings. With this approach you should effectively aggegate out the measurement error.

I made a small simulation and compared this approach with a second approach in which I used all possible pairings per bucket to estimate the correlation. The results show, the aggregation method is better in recovering the original correlation:

```
# I use R and the mvtnorm library to generate the data
library(mvtnorm)

set.seed(12345) # make reproducible

nbuckets <- 50  #number of buckets
r.buckets <- 0.5  # correlation across buckets

# generate data
Cor <- array(c(1, r.buckets, r.buckets, 1), dim=c(2,2))
d.bucket <- rmvnorm(nbuckets, sigma = Cor)
measurement.error = 0.5 # size of eror in relation to sd of the data
data <- vector("list", nbuckets)

for (bucket in seq_len(nbuckets)) {
    data[[bucket]] <- list(x = rep(d.bucket[bucket, 1], 3) + rnorm(3, measurement.error), y = rep(d.bucket[bucket, 2], 3) + rnorm(3, sd = measurement.error))
}
# Note that there are separate error terms for the two types of measurements 

# aggregating per bucket:
data.agg <- lapply(data, function(x) data.frame(x = mean(x[[1]]), y = mean(x[[2]])))
data.agg <- do.call("rbind", data.agg)
cor(data.agg$x, data.agg$y) # should give .408

# using all pairs:
all.pairs <- lapply(data, function(x) data.frame(x = x[[1]], y = x[[2]][c(1:3,3:1,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,3,2,3,1,2)]))
all.pairs <- do.call("rbind", all.pairs)
cor(all.pairs$x, all.pairs$y) # should give .321
```

If you allow for even larger measurement error (although it already is large) the difference remains. If you allow for a single error term within each bucket the results will be a lot nearer to the real value of r and the difference between the methods will decrease. However, aggregating remains the better tactic.

I recommend you play around with it a little with more realistic values. You may even implement a bootstrap approach as was your initial thought.

Comment: That's interesting - I never would have guessed that result.